# How to vectorize scipy.integrate.quad to calculate elementwise integral of a matrix

Tags: python, scipy, vectorization, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a matrix such that each element of the output matrix is integral of the corresponding element of the integrand matrix. Code snippets are as below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
N=3
A = np.random.rand(N,N)
evs = np.linalg.eigvals(A)
evs = -np.sort(-evs)
Anew = A/(evs[0]+1) - np.eye(N)
B = np.eye(N)

def integrand(t,A,B):
    prod = np.multiply(sp.linalg.expm(A*t),B)
    return np.multiply(prod,prod.T)
```

This gives a square matrix with each element a function of t. I use the following to integrate:

```
np.vectorize(quad)(integrand,0,1,args=(Anew,B))
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
integrand() missing 1 required positional argument: 'B'
```

Although this states that 'B' is missing, I don't understand it as I am providing B as an argument. I am also not sure if I am implementing vectorization correctly.

Comment: Don't use `np.vectorize`!  It's not fast(er), and often not easy to use.  Just do a (flat) iteration over the relevant parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try `scipy.integrate.quad_vec`. It's not yet released, so you'll need the in-development version of scipy, which is available from github. Or, wait until scipy 1.4 is released.